# how to AND a big number of arrays of numbers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures

I have 200 arrays of sorted positive integers (some of them have over a million of numbers). I need to find the first number that exists in every array. What would you suggest?

Comment: comment deleted ---------------------------------------------------

Comment: The method `Arrays.binarySearch()`

Comment: A more fitting description than "AND" may be "intersection".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Keep an index on every array.
- Start with the first number of the first array as reference.
- Is the first number of the n-th array lower than the reference, increase its index.
- Is the first number of the n-th array equal to the reference, increase n and proceed with - the next array.
- Is the first number of the n-th array higher than the reference, use that number as reference and start over.
- If n == 201, your reference exists in every array.

Edit: a code example:

```
while n < len(data):
    item = data[n][indices[n]]
    if item < reference:
        indices[n] += 1
    elif item == reference:
        n += 1
    elif item > reference:
        reference = item
        n = 0

print reference
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a k-way merge on the arrays and check for the first element that appears `k` times.

An alternative is creating a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), and chose the first element that appears `k` time in the histogram. A histogram in java can be implemented easily by a `Map<Element,Integer>`

Both solutions are `O(kn)` where `k` is the number of arrays and `n` is the average size of an array, so it is basically linear in the size of the input.